# Retrieving only some fields in RedBean

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbean

I'm using RedBean ORM to write some code and I was wondering if i can load/retrive only some fields from db table.
I know there is a load method but it gives whole table as bean. I wish to get only some fields?

Heh, when i wrote it, I started wondering if it's not against RedBean pattern(or ORM), because getting only some values will create invalid(with only some values) object/bean? I wanted to make some lazy loading of values... maybe there is some other ORM(as easy as RedBean:) to achive this?

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense to load just some fields from a record:

- By selecting less fields you won't decrease the number of queries
- It wont decrease the amount of data that needs to be transferred (this is more related to the number of rows)

Also, RedBeanPHP already lazy-loads all relational fields, so there is no need to do this manual. If you are interested in only a single cell use:

```
R::getCell("select title from document where id = 1");
```

Or to just grab some fields from a record:

```
R::getRow("select id,title from document where... ");
```

These functions return records, not beans, this is the fastest way to deal with simple fields and rows.

Hopefully this answer helps...

Comment: Sorry but I will have to disagree. Imagine a blog. It has 200 posts with a lot of text in the `body` property of each one. If you want to show a list of all posts you can easily run out of memory loading the `body` property of them all. But the thing is you don't need the `body` to show the list. Selective loading would save the day here. But anyway, I love your ORM and you did a really great job. Thank you so much :D